# How to write a jquery plugin in OO way

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i have written following jquery plugin. what i am trying to do is, when the user click on a link make the relevant div display: block base on the data attribute. But this plugin does not work. i have bn trying to figure this out for last two days. But i failed.

My HTML

```
<div class="container1">
    <a href="#" class="link1" data-link="a">asd</a>
    <div class="window1" data-window="a">
           asd         
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container2">
    <a href="#" class="link2" data-link="b">asdf1</a>
    <a href="#" class="link2" data-link="c">asdf2</a>
    <a href="#" class="link2" data-link="d">asdf3</a>
    <div class="window2" data-window="b">
           asdf1         
    </div>
    <div class="window2" data-window="c">
           asdf2        
    </div>
    <div class="window2" data-window="d">
           asdf3         
    </div>
</div>

<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<script>

    $('.container1').myPlugin({
        link: $('.link1'),
        container : $('.window1')
    });
    $('.container2').myPlugin({
        link: $('.link2'),
        container : $('.window2')
    });

</script>
```

plugin

```
   (function ($, window, document, undefind) {

   MyPlugin = {


    init : function (options, element) {
        $.fn.myPlugin.config = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.config, options);
        var link = $.fn.myPlugin.config.link;                

        link.on('click', this.secondFunc);
    },

    secondFunc : function () {
        var dataLinkId = $(this).data('link'),
            container = $($.fn.myPlugin.config).filter('[data-section="' + dataLinkId + '"]'); 
        container.show();
    }

};

$.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
   return this.each(function () {
        var rezG = Object.create(MyPlugin);
        rezG.init(options, this);
    });
}; 

$.fn.myPlugin.config = {
    link: $('.link'),
    container : $('.container')
};

   })(jQuery, window, document);
```

CSS

```
.window1, .window2 {
    display: none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/K82gg/)

Comment: When you set `$.fn.myPlugin.config`, you setting the config for *every* instance of the plugin, not just each element it's called on.  Also, `$($.fn.myPlugin.config)` makes no sense since `$.fn.myPlugin.config` is an object, not a DOM element or a selector.  Finally, none of your elements have a `data-section` attribute.  P.S. You should really do `var MyPlugin = {};`.

Comment: Thanks @RocketHazmat. I changed the code and updated the link. but still no luck. :( i am new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `var` to make sure your variables are all local and not global.

```
var MyPlugin = {
    // ...
};
```

Also, in the `init` function, you are doing this:

```
$.fn.myPlugin.config = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.config, options);
```

This is *overwriting* `$.fn.myPlugin.config` which is the default options.  This means that *all* elements that call `myPlugin()` will use the same config.  You need to set the config on just the one instance.

```
this.config = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.config, options);
```

Your `secondFunc` doesn't have a reference to the object (`rezG`) instance, so it cannot access the config.  You need to pass that to `secondFunc()`.  One way is to use a closure to capture the instance.

```
secondFunc: function (rezG) {
    return function(){
        var dataLinkId = $(this).data('link'),
            container = $(rezG.config.container).filter(function(){
                return $(this).data('window') == dataLinkId;
            });
        container.show();
    };
}
```

Then you bind it like so:

```
link.on('click', this.secondFunc(this));
```

Note that in `secondFunc`, you need to use `config.container`(not just `config` which is the object), and also your attribute is `data-window`, not `data-section`.

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/K82gg/7/

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin could be as simple as

```
(function ($, window, document, undefind) {
$.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
    // When $(stuff).myPlugin(...) is called
    // this keyword inside of myPlugin function is referencing a set 
    // of elements plugin was called upon
    // e.g. for call like $('.container1').myPlugin();
    // this keyword will reference all elements selected by 
    // $('.container1') not jquery wrapped, 
    // in general it can be a any number.
   return this.each(function pluginImplementation () {
       // Here we iterate over the set, and for each element in the set
       // we do some pretty standard click 
       var container = $(this);
       // I use 'click.myPlugin' event instead just 'click' ale to later on
       // do $(..).off('click.myPlugin') to remove only handlers that were 
       // attached by plugin (a good practice)
       container.on('click.myPlugin', options.linkSelector, function(){               
           var dataLinkId = $(this).data('link');
           container.find('[data-window="' + dataLinkId + '"]').toggle();
       })
   });
};
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ih2502mk/RM4fu/2/)

However the code above may have a problem `luginImplementation ()` function is created on each iteration and if the body of that function would be something more complicated it would be a mess. That is why it's better to create `pluginImplementation ()` outside.

```
(function ($, window, document, undefind) {
    // Notice that pluginImplementation () now accepts parameters
    // They make it possible for pluginImplementation to know which
    // elements it's working with

    function pluginImplementation (container, options) {
        container.on('click.myPlugin', options.linkSelector, function(){               
            var dataLinkId = $(this).data('link');
            container.find('[data-window="' + dataLinkId + '"]').toggle();
        })
    }

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            pluginImplementation($(this), options);
        });
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

The [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ih2502mk/4eNn6/)

That separation may be not good enough. You may want your plugin to be more OOP and what not. So you can go all OOPy like that:

```
(function ($, window, document, undefind) {
    // For that purpose we create a class
    // That describes behavior that our plugin provides
    // 
    function MyPlugin(container, options) {
        this.container = container;
        this.options = options;

        // To the topic of maintainability 
        // This could be parametrised as an option at plugin instantiation
        this.eventName = 'click.myPlugin';
    }

    MyPlugin.prototype.attachClickHandlers = function() {
        var self = this;
        // This gets a little messy with all the thises vs selfs and a 
        // noname function wrapping the handler.
        // The point is to preserve this keyword reference 
        // inside of clickHandler method.
        // If I would have just self.clickHandler as a handler there
        // this keyword inside of self.clickHandler would reference to 
        // whatever $(...).on binds handlers to i.e. triggering element.
        // I need this keyword inside of self.clickHandler to point to 
        // "current" instance of MyPlugin, that's why I have wrapping 
        // function. It just lets me call clickHandler in the right context.
        // clickHandler method also needs to know what link is being clicked
        // so we pass that in as parameter.
        self.container.on(self.eventName, 
                          self.options.linkSelector, 
                          function() {
            self.clickHandler($(this));
        })
    }

    MyPlugin.prototype.clickHandler = function(clickedLink) {
        var dataLinkId = clickedLink.data('link');
        this.container.find('[data-window="' + dataLinkId + '"]').toggle();
    }

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var pluginInstance = new MyPlugin($(this), options);
            pluginInstance.attachClickHandlers();
        });
    };        
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

In this implementation MyPlugin is a class (in javascript sense of the word class) which enables you to tackle each specific point in the way it behaves. and introduce all sorts of  OOP features.

The [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ih2502mk/Q3kgz/)